# Minor stringing issue, only happens in helpers & infill areas

Tags: ultimaker-cura, stringing

I'm having a "minor" stringing issue, where I'm only getting stringing in helpers/support and infill area.

Background: Calibrating printer with 1 roll of PLA. Still getting minimal stringing, but mainly, stringing in helpers/support and infill areas. Tried different temps, but didn't seem to affect this.

Suspect some kind of slicer optimization settings? I mean, it's logical to not care about how pretty supports & infill look.

I would like to understand why this is happening.
Please point me to the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Example photo: Outside in: brim, shell/wall, support, brim.
From [Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4512926).

[image: Photo]

Comment: Hi! Nice photo, shows a lot, thank you. At the same time you did not give any information of your current configuration. What are your current slicer settings: do you retract at all? Maybe too few? What is your slicer? There are many retraction-related detailed settings in Cura's section "Travel". What did you try? How much did you lower a temeparture? I have PLA which starts melting slowly at 150 °C. Maybe yours is still too hot? Did you even went below minum level (of slight underextrusion)? When you are leaving readers with hundreds of questions, there are many possible answers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out: many retraction-related detailed settings in Cura's section "Travel"

Answer (score 1):

If the problem occurs in or immediately following printing of support material, it's probably Cura's *Limit Support Retractions* option, which defaults to on. This is probably the single worst default Cura has, and it causes all sorts of problems - surface defects, difficult-to-remove support, underextrusion, etc. - due to basically skipping all (necessary!) retractions while printing support.

If the problem occurs in infill area, it's probably *Combing*. Lowering *Max Comb Distance With No Retract* to something very low (150-200% of the nozzle width, so like 0.8 mm) should make this problem go away, but at some nontrivial cost to print time. If you make this change, you almost surely need *Zig-zaggify Infill* enabled if you want to avoid very high cost to print time and excessive retractions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could add an image showing the stringing that occurs on the filled and helper/support part of the print. It's quite difficult to visualise what is happening/your problem.

I would assume that the density/fill of the print will be different for infill versus helper/support parts of the print. As a result, there are more gaps in the helper/support parts and stringing can more easily occur between them.

Have you tried enabling z-hop/retraction to prevent further stringing?